# Javascript use ES6 map to extract key from array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I have an array of objects, similar to this:

```
fruits = [
  { name: apple, color: red }, {name: lemon, color: yellow } etc.
]
```

I'm trying to use `map`  to get a new array of just the colors, such as

```
fruitColors = ['red', 'yellow']
```

I'm kinda new to ES6, what's the syntax for this?

Comment: This is not ES6 specific - it's just invoking [`.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
const fruits = [
  { name: 'apple', color: 'red' }, 
  { name: 'lemon', color: 'yellow' }
];

console.log(fruits.map(fruit => fruit.color));

// OR EVEN SHORTER USING DESTRUCTURING
console.log('USING DESTRUCTURING');
console.log(fruits.map(({color}) => color));
```

Comment: Please vote to close duplicates

Answer (score 1):

You can just return the `.color` property from the map:

```
const fruitColors = fruits.map(f => f.color);
```

Also using [`lodash`](https://lodash.com/docs/) or `underscore` you can achieve the same by:

```
const fruitColors = _.map(fruits, 'color');
```

Comment: Please vote to close duplicates

Answer (score 1):

> The map() method creates a new array with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array.

So, basically it goes like this:

```
let colorsArray = fruits.map( (obj) => { 
  return obj.color;
}
```

in es6, when you have an annonymous function with only a return statement you can omit the function square brackets, omit the arguments normal brackets (assuming you have only one argument, which u do in this case) and the return statement, which also makes it possible to write it all on the same line without losing readability, so it becomes:

```js
let colorsArray = fruits.map( obj => obj.color );
```

If you're not familiar with the arrow function syntax, I advise reading more about it ([here](https://codeburst.io/javascript-arrow-functions-for-beginners-926947fc0cdc) is a nice start).

Answer (score 0):

`fruits.map(fruit => fruit.color)`